# Hiding imageView when webView is loading?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, webview

I am trying to show a UIImageView when my UIWebView is loading a page, and hide when it is finished loading.

My ViewController.h:

```
@interface FindViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

}
```

My ViewController.m:

```
@implimentation

-(void)viewDidLoad {

}
if (!webView.loading) {
image.hidden = NO;
} else {
image.hidden = YES;
}
```

However, it's not doing anything! How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use uiimageview as a subview of uiwebview. If you want to handle them manually you can use viewwillload method and use notification to invoke the method for changes.